# Limit items in a shopping list using malloc()?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I am struggling with the function that should add items to a shopping list. I wrote code that works, but I am wondering if there is another way to limit items to 5 by using `malloc()`?

The `length` field should always be containing the index to the last position of the array, so this is where the item should be placed. For instance, `length` is zero when the list is empty,

So the first time this function is called, the item should be placed at index zero in `list->itemArray`.

This function is also responsible for increasing the length of the list.

Since we just added one item, the list is now one item longer.

Just remember that it should not be possible to add more than 5 items to the list.

```
#ifndef SHOPPING_LIST_H
#define SHOPPING_LIST_H


// Struct definitions

struct GroceryItem
{
    char productName[20];
    float amount;
    char unit[10];
};

struct ShoppingList
{
    int length;
    struct GroceryItem itemList[5];
};

// Function declarations

void addItem(struct ShoppingList *list);
void printList(struct ShoppingList *list);
void editItem(struct ShoppingList *list);
void removeItem(struct ShoppingList *list);
void saveList(struct ShoppingList *list);
void loadList(struct ShoppingList* list);

#endif
```

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include "ShoppingList.h"

int main(void)
{
    struct ShoppingList shoppingList;
    shoppingList.length = 0; // The shopping list is empty at the start

    int option;

    do
    {
        printf("\n\nWelcome to the shopping list manager!\n");
        printf("=====================================\n\n");

        printf("1. Add an item\n");
        printf("2. Display the shopping list\n");
        printf("3. Remove an item\n");
        printf("4. Change an item\n");
        printf("5. Save list\n");
        printf("6. Load list\n");
        printf("7. Exit\n");

        printf("What do you want to do? ");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1: addItem(&shoppingList); break;
        case 2: printList(&shoppingList); break;
        case 3: removeItem(&shoppingList); break;
        case 4: editItem(&shoppingList); break;
        case 5: saveList(&shoppingList); break;
        case 6: loadList(&shoppingList); break;
        case 7: break;
        default:
            printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 7");
        }
    } while (option != 7);

    return 0;
}
```

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include"ShoppingList.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> // For malloc() and free()



/*

The “length” field should always be containing the index to the last position of the array,
so this is where the item should be placed. For instance, length is zero when the list is empty,
so the first time this function is called, the item should be placed at index zero in list->itemArray. 

This function is also responsible for increasing the length of the list.
Since we just added one item, the list is now one item longer. 
Just remember that it should not be possible to add more than 5 items to the list.

   */

void addItem(struct ShoppingList* list)
{
    if (list->length > 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Name for product: ");
    scanf("%s", list->itemList[list->length].productName);

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the amount: ");
        scanf("%f", &list->itemList[list->length].amount);

        if (list->itemList[list->length].amount <= 0.0)
        {
            printf("Input is invalid.\n");
        }

    } while (list->itemList[list->length].amount <= 0.0);


    printf("Enter unit of item: ");
    scanf("%s", list->itemList[list->length].unit);

    printf("%s was added to the shoppinglist.", list->itemList[list->length].productName);

    list->length++;
}
```

Comment: In the `addItem` function you have the check `if (list->length > 4)`. That will limit the list to four elements, no matter if you use pointers and dynamic allocation, or a plain array (like you do now).

Comment: Aside: `scanf("%s"...` without a _width_ for `"%s"` like `"%19s"` is not robust coding.

Comment: If I would like to change the limit to infinity, because of the fact that I don't know how many items user will put in the list, what would the best solution in this case? Thank you for the answer I really appreciate it.

Comment: Pointers, keeping track of size (number of used elements) and capacity (number of elements allocated), `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you please show me an example? I dont really get it. Thank you for the answer.